# How to join or push all the values into a single variable within each loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a sample json structure. Here I am getting all the values into alert using each loop of jquery withing success function of a ajax call. I am getting the proper value in alert, but I am getting one by one, I need to get all into a single alert may be using push or join or split which should be separated by just space, I am not getting actually what I need to do here.

Below is the code and also I have updated the code into the following plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/KhFhW4Z3Kk4QwvRDr1pX?p=preview

### html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">

</div>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
```

### script.js

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '1.json',
  success: function(result) {
    var parents = {};
    $.each(result, function(val) {
    var newjoinval = result[val].name+"-"+result[val].value
    alert(newjoinval);

    });

  }
});
```

### 1.json

```
[{
    "name": "parent1",
    "value": ["child11", "child12"]
}, {
    "name": "parent2",
    "value": ["child2"]
}, {
    "name": "parent3",
    "value": ["child3"]
}]
```

Comment: Use the operator `+=` to append data to a string variable and alert the result **after** the each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing the `alert` with individual item in each iteration of `result`. You can generate the string in the form you want with `map()` and `join()` with space () character before showing it in the `alert`.

Change the `success` like the following:

```
success: function(result) {
  var parents = {};
  var newjoinval = result.map(p => p.name+"-"+p.value).join(' ');
  alert(newjoinval);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var result = [{
    "name": "parent1",
    "value": ["child11", "child12"]
}, {
    "name": "parent2",
    "value": ["child2"]
}, {
    "name": "parent3",
    "value": ["child3"]
}];

var newjoinval = result.map(p => p.name+"-"+p.value).join(' ');
alert(newjoinval);
```